# Reference npm script from npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

Consider the following example `package.json` fragment:

```
{
   // ...
   "scripts": {
       "start": "npm run b -- --watch",
       "build": "builder --in src --out dest"
   }
   // ...
}
```

In this, I run `build` from `start`, and give it an extra flag. The problem with this approach is it actually creates another instance of the NPM run. It works, but it's ugly.

Is there a clean way to reference the `build` command from the `start` command without having to make another call to NPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a clean way to reference the build command from the start command without having to make another call to NPM?

Not really.

If you just don't like `npm`'s verbose output, you can silence that with `npm run b -s -- --watch`.

If you are calling multiple npm scripts from one parent script, you may want to look into an npm task runner. Here is a list of a few: https://github.com/RyanZim/awesome-npm-scripts#task-runners. (Disclaimer: `awesome-npm-scripts` is my personal project)